# Wordpress feed - (A feed could not be found at)

Tags: wordpress, rss

I had set up two Wordpress development sites, URL's were something like mysite.com/dev/blog1 and mysite.com/dev/blog2. blog2 would fetch posts from categories on blog1 using fetch_feed() e.g. fetch_feed(mysite.com/dev/blog1/category/fun/feed) and everything worked fine.

However, since moving the sites over to mysite.com/blog1 and mysite.com/blog2, the feed does not work. I get the following error:

A feed could not be found at mysite.com/blog1/category/fun/feed. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are certain this URL is a real feed." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

When I go to the feed URL though, the feed does exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch_feed()` function is still trying to look at the dev. Highlighted below:

"A feed could not be found at `mysite.com/dev/blog1/category/fun/feed`. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall vic....."

You will need to remove the `dev` part from the url.

Comment: Sorry, I entered the error incorrectly, it says "A feed could not be found at mysite.com/blog1/category/fun/feed" - the URL is correct.

Comment: The feed is indeed active, if I visit the feed URL for the live site, I can see the XML and it contains URL's for the live site, not dev

Comment: htaccess is the standard Wordpress one with no additional RSS rules

One thing I realized is that the site is being moved to another server but the DNS has not been updated. I have updated my local hosts file though. So could the DNS not being updated be causing the  issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I've tried different Wordpress RSS plugins and got the same result: "RSS Error: A feed could not be found at ..."
(For almost all RSS feeds except for feeds from feedburner!)

I contacted our provider / web hosting service, they "unlocked" the domain of the rss feed within a minute and now it works perfectly!

If you're using a webhoster, maybe you need to contact their support for help.