# Wordpress Reader error - An RSS or Atom feed could not be found for that blog

Tags: wordpress, rss

Well, I found this stackoverflow question [Wordpress feed - (A feed could not be found at)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347388/wordpress-feed-a-feed-could-not-be-found-at)

Since there are no accepted answers there and I don't have the reputation to add comments to that question, I am adding this question.

Some of the feeds with which I faced issues when adding to Wordpress reader are the following:

http://msopentech.com/feed/

http://www.dwheeler.com/blog/index.rss

Comment: "I faced issues when adding to Wordpress reader" What do you mean exactly? What are the  *issues* you're seeing?

Comment: I meant this [http://imgur.com/dL4COmX](http://imgur.com/dL4COmX)

Answer (score 0):

the first feed, msopentech.com/feed/, is pretty slow (takes > 10s to load, Wordpress.com stops trying after 3s currently), which is triggering the error.

The second is broken because it's using a mimetype of text/plain instead of application/rss+xml.

Comment: Thanks, I sent msopentech.com a message reg. the timeout issue. Let's see.